# How can I have the date from today show up with PHP?

Tags: php, function, date, variables

I'm sending a mail function to myself.

My first line reads 'Order for $name on $date'
The $name variable comes from a form the user fills out.
I would like the $date variable to be today's date, whatever that is on that day.

How can I make the $date variable show today's date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$date = date('m/d/Y');
```

see http://en.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php for the syntax of date()

Comment: I'd prefer date('Y-m-d'), so that it's ISO-8601 ;)

Comment: You have a good point, but that is up to him.
For non interational uses I'd go with m/d/Y (d/m/Y really since I'm Italian ;)

Answer (score 1):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php The date() function does that.

Answer (score 0):

This puts today's [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in a string, all ready to be stuck into the DB :).

```
$todays_date_string = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```